Hide url in angular 16
How can I hide the url shown when inspected in ANGULAR 16 as I'm getting the data from dropbox by using raw=1 at the end and storing the link in api and fetching that.
This is for a website where my personal videos are played, so don't want them to be accessd easily with the link
loadVideo(videoLink: string): void {
        this.videoLink = videoLink;
         setTimeout(() => {
        this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.src = this.videoLink;
        this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.load();
            this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.play();
            this.isLoading = false;
        }, 2000);
    }
 ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.initializeVideo();
        this.ngAfterViewInit2();
        if(this.ClassDetails?.VideoLink != undefined){
            this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.load();
            this.ClassProgress = this.ClassDetails.Progress ? this.ClassDetails.Progress : 0;
        }
    }


You can't hide the URL. The browser needs it to play the video, therefore the user can also find it with the browser tools.

you can only make sure the request is authorized on the backend.  The destination will be known.  You can set the src to an endpoint passing something like the UID for the file.  The endpoint can then authenticate/authorize the request and return the file.  (Make sure only the backend code can read the folder that stores the files... otherwise a deep link could be guessed and bypass your authorization code)

UPDATE Really I'm not prety sure you can get the video using any extension of the navigator, so I proceed to strike the answer

Really you can not hide the url, but you can take another approach: "dirty" the file.
E.g. if you have a file 'video-real.mp4', you can create a file 'video.mp4' that have some "characters at first"

Create a file fool.txt with some text, e.g.
Personal


Create a file concatenate the two files
  type fool.txt video-real.mp4 >video.mp4



this "video.pm4" can not be "loaded and playing"
To play de video, you read the file as ArrayBuffer, remove the first 8 bytes and play
//see the "responseType:arrayBuffer"
this.httpClient.get('https://www.dominio.com/video.mp4',
                                         {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
  .subscribe((res:any)=>{

   //remove the first 8 characters 
   //(the word "Personal" that have our fool.txt file have 8 characters)
    const blob=new Blob([res.slice(8)]); 

    //create an url Object
    const url = URL.createObjectURL( blob );

    //search an html tag with "video"
    const video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

    //equal the src
    video.src = url;

    //make a load
      video.load();

    //when loaded, play
    video.onloadeddata = function() {
       video.play();
    }
}

NOTE: Instead search by tagname the "video" you can use ViewChild and get the nativeElement
NOTE2: Really it's a poor tecnica, any with a few knowledge can download the file and remove the first 8 characters, it's only for inspiration.

